# How do I refresh directory in BASH?

Tags: linux, bash, filesystems

I have a directory, containing files generated by compiler. During each rebuild this directory gets cleaned and, after build process `ls` gives me empty output. After I `cd` out of directory and then back to it ls works right. 
The questions are:

1. Is there any other, more elegant way to refresh directory?
2. What actually happens when files deleted and recreated? Why do I need to `cd` to see actual directory content?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your script is most likely removing the directory, and not just the files which are there.  So, when you have `cd`'d into it, and the directory is removed, you do `ls` on a directory which does not actually exist.

By `cd ..` and `cd (directory)` you move up and back into the (newly created) directory, and the files are there as you expect.

The best alternative is instead of `cd`ing in and out of the directory, is to add the directory name to your `ls` command, and run it from the parent directory.  So, `ls YourSubdirectory` instead of just `ls`.

Comment: In my case, I had to .. up 3 levels to get the replaced directories. So the solution here won't always work.  Surprisingly, cd . does. And the cd `pwd` even makes sense.

Answer (score 72):

There is even a shorter way:
`cd .`

Comment: Interesting. Like the hummingbird, this, logically, should not work -- and yet it appears that it does. I presume that you know that it works because you've tried it. Do you have any documentation for it? I.e., if I were on the POSIX/bash development team, I would be tempted to consider this a bug. Do you know of any documentation that says that it's _supposed_ to work this way?

Comment: Like the falcon, this, beautifully, floats above the flowers -- and yet it devours hummingbirds.

Comment: Yes! so perfect

Comment: This is the better answer.

Comment: Ah. I knew it! There had to be a way. Thanks!

Comment: that is the answer!

Answer (score 11):

It looks odd, but it is short and refreshes the directory:

```
cd `pwd`
```

Note those are back ticks, not single quotes around the pwd

Answer (score 3):

It would be better if you did not remove the directory, but instead of `cd ..; cd -` you could do `cd $PWD`.

Answer (score 2):

What @Kent said or: don't remove the directory but only its contents, this way you can stay in the directory (without "`cd .. && cd -`") and "ls" does what you expected it to do.

Answer (score 2):

create an alias refresh="cd .. && cd -" that will go a directory up and then again cd into the previous directory

if you are sure that you will need a listing again you can have

```
alias refresh="cd .. && cd - && ls -lrt"
```

once the ailas is create store the alias into your ~/.bashrc file by doing

```
alias | grep refresh >> ~/.bashrc
```

so that it is available next time you login.

Comment: In Unix `refresh` is out-of-box.

Comment: What do you mean by "out-of-box"? When I saw it, I interpreted it to mean "standard"; now I'm wondering what you mean. Define "UNIX". Cygwin does not have a "refresh" command standard (OK, Cygwin is missing a lot of things that are standard in POSIX/*nix/whatever), and neither does my Linux system.